# iptables, NAT question

Tags: iptables, nat

What is the iptables command to achieve the following rule as reported by 
sudo iptables -t nat -L -n -v

```
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 133 packets, 10675 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   74  4322 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *       10.42.0.0/24        !10.42.0.0/24
```

Comment: you can see it by yourself by doing `iptables -t nat -S POSTROUTING`

Comment: Thank you. I also found it the hard way  
~~~
sudo iptables --table nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.42.0/24 ! -d 192.168.42.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
~~~

Answer (score 2):

As prompted by LL3 above one option is:

```
sudo iptables -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.42.0/24 ! -d 192.168.42.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

and another which implicitly refers to the nat table, which I used, is

```
sudo iptables --table nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.42.0/24 ! -d 192.168.42.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: Please note that I prompted a command that prints all current rules of a specific chain, showing the syntax you would need to use to replicate those rules, so that you can see by yourself how a particular rule as shown by `-L` can be obtained on the command line. Also note that `-S` output is always relative to the **table and chain** you specify, meaning that to replicate the same rule you need to specify the table explicitly if it is not the `-t filter` one. For this reason your first example here will not work because the `POSTROUTING` chain does not exist in the `-t filter` table.